# Ajax не идет отправка

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

```
         Таких там 3 штуки,но почему-то работает только с 1
        <div class="row">
         {foreach name=aussen from=$Whisted item=box}

                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                                <div class="card card-pricing card-raised">
                                    <div class="content">
                                        <h6 class="category">{$box_news_data.LOGIN}</h6>
                                        <div class="icon icon-rose">
                                        <img src="{$box.GA}" style="width: 200; height: 200">
                                        </div>
                                        <h3 class="card-title">{$box.BAL}₽</h3>
                                        <p class="card-description">

                                        </p>

                                         <input type='text' id='id' value="{$box.ID}">
                                        <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-rose btn-round">Купить на {$box.DATE}</button>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>


 {/foreach}



        </div>




     $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submit").click(function(){
        var name = $("#id").val();

        // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
        var dataString = 'check=1'+ '&id_tovar='+ name;
        if(name=='')
        {
        alert("Ошибка");
        }
        else
        {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "item_success.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: true,
        success: function(result){
        if(result != '1')
        {
        swal({ title:"Успешная покупка", text: "", type: "success", buttonsStyling: false, confirmButtonClass: "btn btn-success"});

        }
        else
        {
        swal({ title:"Ошибка покупки", text: "Пополните баланс", type: "error", buttonsStyling: false, confirmButtonClass: "btn btn-danger"});
        }
        }
        });
        }
        return false;
        });
        });
```

Comment: потому что у них одинаковые `id`

Comment: А как мне искать разные id ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените повторяющиеся `id` на классы:

```
<input type='text' class='id-input' value="{$box.ID}">
<button type="submit" class="submit-btn btn btn-rose btn-round">Купить на {$box.DATE}</button>

$(".submit-btn").click(function(e){
  var name = $(this).parent().find(".id-input").val();
  ...

  result false;
});
```

Comment: Спасибо,работает. Теперь буду знать.